# Mimicing TCP with UDP - Anything wrong with using packets instead of 'bytes' for window size?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, network-programming, sliding-window

I'm writing a TCP implementation, using UDP sockets. My initial algorithm will be based off TCP Reno. My question is, since packets are byte-sized anyways, would there be any significant downsides to implementing the sliding window using `maxNum Packets` rather than `maxNum Bytes`? Isn't it pretty much the same thing?

For some code example, I currently do a `mmap()` on my data, and then pack it into a `map`:

```
int
ReliableSender::Packetize(char* data, int numBytes)
{
    int seqNum = 1;
    int offset = 0;
    char* payload = NULL;
    unsigned int length = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    bool dataRemaining = true;
    while(dataRemaining)
    {
        size_t packetSize;
        (numBytes > MTU) ? packetSize = MTU : packetSize = numBytes;
        memcpy(payload, data, packetSize);
        Packet pac = {seqNum, 0, payload};

        dataMap.insert(make_pair(seqNum, pac));

        if(numBytes > MTU)
            payload = &data[offset];
        else
            dataRemaining = false;

        offset += MTU;
        numBytes -= MTU;
        seqNum++;
    }

    return 0;
}

struct Packet
{
    int seqNum;
    int ackNum; 
    char* payload;
};
```

My thought was that I could simply adjust the sliding window by increasing the number of "packets" I send without an `ACK` rather than a set number of bytes - is there anything wrong with this? This is for a very simple application; nothing that needs to be portable or placed into production anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. TCP is a byte-stream protocol. You can send one byte at a times you can therefore change the receive window by one the at a time. You therefore can't express the receive window in packets.

If packets are byte-size you're just wasting bandwidth.